# unset a Json in laravel and reindex it

Tags: php, laravel

I get an error:

> array_values() expects parameter 1 to be array, object given

below is my code:

```
for($a=0; $a < sizeOf($participations); $a++){
    foreach($winners as $winner){
        if($winner->id == $participations[$a]->id){
            Log::info($participations);
            unset($participations[$a]);
            Log::info($participations);

        }
    }

}
$participations1 = array_values($participations);
```

before unset I get:

```
[2015-09-10 13:25:21] local.INFO: [{"id":6,"campaignId":7,"userId":9,"created_at":"2015-09-08 16:23:48","updated_at":"2015-09-08 16:23:49","isCorrect":1},{"id":7,"campaignId":7,"userId":10,"created_at":"2015-09-09 11:47:04","updated_at":"2015-09-09 11:47:05","isCorrect":1},{"id":8,"campaignId":7,"userId":11,"created_at":"2015-09-09 11:47:16","updated_at":"2015-09-09 11:47:16","isCorrect":1}] [] []
```

after unset I get:

```
[2015-09-10 13:25:21] local.INFO: 
{"0":{"id":6,"campaignId":7,"userId":9,"created_at":"2015-09-08 16:23:48","updated_at":"2015-09-08 16:23:49","isCorrect":1},"2":{"id":8,"campaignId":7,"userId":11,"created_at":"2015-09-09 11:47:16","updated_at":"2015-09-09 11:47:16","isCorrect":1}} [] []
```

the participation is not an array at all so, how can use `array_values()` to re-index the Json

Comment: This is not array. This is JSON.

Comment: ok thx~ i will do a research on JSON

Comment: use `json_decode()` function to return it as an array